# Docker-compose: keep on getting can't "This site can’t be reached

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm kind of new to this. I'm trying to dockerize my node js application

I've created a Docker File

```
FROM node:7
# Working directory for application
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
# Binds to port 7777
EXPOSE 7777
# Creates a mount point
VOLUME [ "/usr/src/app" ]
```

and this is my docker-compose.yml file

```
version: "2"
services:
  redis:
    image: "redis"
  postgres:
    image: "postgres:9.4"  
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
     - "4000:4000"
    volumes:
     - .:/usr/src/app
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - redis
    command: ["npm", "start"]
```

Now I ran docker-compose up -d and I'm not getting any error. But the problem is when I try to access it using this url `0.0.0.0:4000` it throws me this error "this site can't be reached"

Can you guys help me out thanks

**UPDATE: **

I have found the ip using this command

```
docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}'  helloworld_web_1
```

which is this --> `172.21.0.4`

but when I try to access it using the above URL it still `http://172.21.0.4:4000/`

it still refuses to connect

Comment: `0.0.0.0` isn't a real IP; use `localhost` instead.

Comment: @TJBiddle on localhost it gives me this error `This page isn’t working. localhost didn’t send any data.`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [This site can’t be reached docker-compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60361324/this-site-can-t-be-reached-docker-compose)

Answer (score 0):

Under `ports`, the docker image will not be able to accept that the internal port is 4000. WordPress's internal default port is at 80. Hence, you will need to change the script within `docker-compose.yml` to be `4000:80` instead. After re-running the DockerFile, you should then be able to access the WordPress site with the internet browser.

Comment: Erm... shouldn't this be `4000:7777` as it specifies 7777 as the port in the Dockerfile? Is nobody seeing this?