# This site can’t be reached docker-compose

Tags: reactjs, docker, docker-compose, webpack-dev-server

I am trying to use docker-compose for `react-typescript` application with `webpack-dev-server` below is my **Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:lts-slim

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

EXPOSE 3000

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

`"start": "webpack-dev-server --port 3000"` this `package.json` line

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3"
services:
    frontend:
        container_name: awesome_web
        build:
            context: ./client
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        image: webpack
        ports:
            - "3000:3000"
        volumes:
            - ./client:/usr/src/app
```

I executed command **docker-compose up --build** based on logs application compiled successfully

output of **docker ps**

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
c88198ba996c        webpack             "docker-entrypoint.s…"   21 seconds ago      Up 20 seconds       0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp   awesome_web
```

but when I am trying to access **localhost:3000** I am getting error **This site can’t be reached**

I am new to docker, following online blogs but I am not able to get why am I not able reach site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing your `start` script to:

```js
webpack-dev-server --host 0.0.0.0 --port 3000
```

And your Dockerfile to:

```
FROM node:lts-slim

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . /usr/src/app/

EXPOSE 3000

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

*Note: I highly advise against running your containers as root. You should always downgrade your user with the command `USER ...`*.

#### Security

According to [this Snyk's report](https://snyk.io/test/docker/node%3Alts-slim), you are using a vulnerable base image in addition to running it as root. I highly recommend you use [this image](https://snyk.io/test/docker/node%3A13.8.0-alpine) instead. Furthermore, you should run your image as a [non-root user](https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/master/docs/BestPractices.md#non-root-user):

```
FROM node:13.8.0-alpine

# don't run as root
RUN addgroup -S app_group && adduser -S -G app_group app_user

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app && chown app_user /usr/src/app

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY --chown=app_user:app_group . /usr/src/app/

EXPOSE 3000

USER node
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
USER app_user
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using docker toolkit then there is virtual machine running for each container check your current container is running on which virtual machine get vm ip and browse with this url vm-ip:3000 
Or if you are just running docker then try to open docker 0.0.0.0:3000 .